# Accessing combo box data model

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qjson

I'm sending a `QJsonArray` from C++ to QML combo box:

netlib.h

```
void discoveryResultChanged(const QJsonArray jsonArray);
```

netlib.cpp

```
QByteArray answer_ba = reply->readAll();
QJsonDocument answer_json_doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(answer_ba);
QJsonObject answer_json_obj = answer_json_doc.object();
QJsonArray answer_json_array = answer_json_obj["printers_array"].toArray();
qDebug() << __func__ << "JSON array: " << answer_json_array;
emit discoveryResultChanged(answer_json_array);
```

*.qml

```
    ColumnLayout {
        id: printersColumn
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 8
        Layout.bottomMargin: 8
        Layout.topMargin: 8

        visible: !netlib.discoveryInProgress

        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width

            ComboBox {
                id: printers
                width: parent.width
                anchors.margins: 4
                textRole: "name"
            }

            Connections {
                target: netlib
                onDiscoveryResultChanged: {
                    printers.model = jsonArray // ComboBox model is set to QJsonArray
                }
            }
        }

        RowLayout {
            TextArea {
                text: printers.currentText
                // How to access `printers` ComboBox data model here?
                // I need to access key/values of QJsonArray ... how?
            }
        }

    }
```

The sample `QJsonArray` is

QJsonArray([{"ip":"10.10.2.22","name":"N 0","port":4000,"profiles_array":[{"config":"0 blah blah blah","id":0,"name":"Profile 0-0"},{"config":"1 blah blah blah","id":1,"name":"Profile 0-1"},{"config":"2 blah blah blah","id":2,"name":"Profile 0-2"}]},{"ip":"192.168.1.1","name":"N 1","port":4001,"profiles_array":[{"config":"0 blah blah blah","id":0,"name":"Profile 1-0"},{"config":"1 blah blah blah","id":1,"name":"Profile 1-1"},{"config":"2 blah blah blah","id":2,"name":"Profile 1-2"}]},{"ip":"172.16.1.1","name":"N 2","port":4003,"profiles_array":[{"config":"0 blah blah blah","id":0,"name":"Profile 2-0"},{"config":"1 blah blah blah","id":1,"name":"Profile 2-1"},{"config":"2 blah blah blah","id":2,"name":"Profile 2-2"}]}])

---

How can I access key/values of ComboBox model `QJsonArray` from within the `TextArea` on my QML code?

Comment: Ehhm... what about 'printers.model'?

Comment: @folibis Thanks! Actually it worked: `text: "Printer IP: " + printers.model[printers.currentIndex].ip +
                    "\nPrinter Port: " + printers.model[printers.currentIndex].port`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, I could access `JsonArray` model key/values of `ComboBox` with id `printers` from within my `TextArea`:

```
 TextArea {
     text: "Printer IP: " + printers.model[printers.currentIndex].ip +
         "\nPrinter Port: " + printers.model[printers.currentIndex].port
 }
```